# How to translate other text in Javascript with jquery-lang-js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, translation, lang

I' using the [jquery-lang-js](https://github.com/Irrelon/jquery-lang-js)  plugin to translate dynamically different parts of my webpage associated with HTML elements.

It works with static elements. Now I want to translate parts of strings of elements included in a JSON array which I call within a function in my JS file.

I found the following instruction in the documentation:

[image: instruction from the site of the owner of the plugin]

Let's suppose I want to translate the following string in spanish:

> "Leg 22: Rome-London"

i.e. the result will be the following:

> "Etapa 22: Rome-London"

Therefore the `'Some text to translate'` mentioned in the javascript method above will be "Leg".

I added the part of string I want to translate ("Leg") in my language packages (for example, in the es.js it's :

```
{
"token": {    
        "Leg": "Etapa"
          }
}
```

Now I have to place the following line of code somewhere in the js file:

```
window.lang.translate("Leg");
```

Is it correct reasoning?
If so, where should I write the method() mentioned above?